# Recommendation of WinApp IPCONFIG replacement

Tags: ipconfig

I'm getting tired of having to open a command prompt to run IPCONFIG -- only to have the important details scroll off the screen.  Can anyone recommend a window app (preferably free/OSS) that does the same things?

Comment: Why is this a CW by the way?

Comment: It's an opinion question without a single definite answer.

Comment: Not really though. Asking for an application that fulfills a specific need but has slightly different features isn't opinion. Asking which people prefer would be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best I've found in [Win Ip Config](http://www.pkostov.com/wipcfg.html) by Peter Kostov's Software.

Answer (score 2):

You could always pipe it into `more`.

```
ipconfig /all|more
```

I really wish Windows had a native `less` implementation.